# How to identify the argument action if the destinations of argparse argument are the same?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--download',
                    action='store',
                    dest='request_file',
                    help='download request file from server')
parser.add_argument('--upload',
                    action='store',
                    dest='request_file',
                    help='download request file from server')

arguments = parser.parse_args()
request_file = arguments.request_file
```

How can I distinguish the actions between download and upload from the argument?

Something like this

```
if arguments.download:
    download(request_file)
if arguments.upload:
    upload(request_file)
```

Comment: It is because I want to make it like this. `python mycode.py --upload FILE`

Comment: Why are they the same actions in the first place? It doesn't seem like ``--upload`` should *download* a file.

Comment: Actually, I would like to see two different actions, either `download` or `upload`, will use the same variable `request_file`.

Comment: An alternative would be to make the `--download` and `--upload` `'store_true'` actions, and add a 'request' positional argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--download',
                    metavar='FILE',
                    help='download request file from server')
parser.add_argument('--upload',
                    metavar='FILE',
                    help='download request file from server')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.download is not None:
    download(args.download)
if args.upload is not None:
    upload(args.upload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you (probably) don't expect the user to both upload and download at the same time, I recommend making the flags mutually exclusive:

```
import argparse

parser = ArgumentParser()
updown = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
updown.add_argument('--download',
                    action='store',
                    dest='request_file',
                    help='download request file from server')
updown.add_argument('--upload',
                    action='store',
                    dest='request_file',
                    help='upload request file from server')

arguments = parser.parse_args()
request_file = arguments.request_file
```

Then you can use the code posted in your answer, but modified slightly:

```
if arguments.download:
    download(request_file)
elif arguments.upload:
    upload(request_file)
```

Comment: How does this help?  You still get a error looking for `arguments.download`

Comment: That was not mentioned as part of the original question, which was: "How can I distinguish the actions between download and upload from the argument?"

Comment: mutuallyexclusive keeps you from using both in one command, but doesn't help identify which was used.